# How to get specific ID from Parent to Child component with Input decorator Single page

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass from Parent component through foreach specific id with Input decorator to Child component /lazy loading/. But when I click show more loads all 6 id's, how can I avoid that.

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJfSj.png)
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWOnK.png)

Parent - products.component

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products">
<div *ngIf="popup">
  <app-product [openModal]="popup" [results]="product"></app-product>
</div>
<div class="style">
  <button class="btn btn-primary"
          type="button" (click)="popup = true">Show more
  </button>
  <div *ngFor="let prices of product.prices">
    <div class="box col">
     <span class="mr-1">{{prices.price}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<span class="text-center">{{product.title}}</span>
```

Child - product.component

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() openModal: any;
@Input() results: any;

constructor() {
   }
}

<div class="overlay" *ngIf="openModal">
<div class="popup">
<a class="close" (click)="openModal = false">&times;</a>
<div class="content">
  
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for having Your popup inside a loop. As there is only one "global" flag for opening/closing Your component (`popup`) then if You click on any of the "Show more" buttons all of these `app-product` will get `[openModal]="true"` so they will show up all at once.

What You need to do instead is set the `popup` value and something like `currentProduct` to one You selected. Then pass it to the component (outside the loop). Even better maybe You can just delete the `[openModal]="popup"` and connect visibility of the modal to the nullability of the `currentProduct`? So the modal will be shown only if You have selected the product (on "show more") and You then need to set it to `null` on an event on modal close:

```
<app-product [results]="currentProduct" (onClose)="currentProduct = null"></app-product>

<div *ngFor="let product of products">
<div class="style">
  <button class="btn btn-primary"
          type="button" (click)="currentProduct = product">Show more
  </button>
  <div *ngFor="let prices of product.prices">
    <div class="box col">
     <span class="mr-1">{{prices.price}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<span class="text-center">{{product.title}}</span>
```

and in child component add `@Output() onClose = new EventEmitter()`, instead of `(click)="openModal = false"` pass the event to the parent like so: `(click)="onClose.emit()"`.

Of course I agree that it would be simpler to use some existing components for modals like already mentioned Angural Material but hey, it is not the only choise we have.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, I already fix the issue, as I saw your answer just now, here is the solution which helped me - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-parent-child?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.html

Answer (score 0):

INstead Of Doing Child Parent Just Use Angular Material Dialog So It Easy To Pass And Retrive Data From That here Is link https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview
For that